# Clearing background Image from body in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

so I have a probably very simple question, but as always, those seem to be the hardest to solve. So I have this icon in the AppBar in Flutter:

```
 appBar: AppBar(
    
    actions: <Widget>[
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.add_a_photo, color: Colors.white),
        onPressed: () => _getImage(),
      ),
      //this should be clear image button
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.clear,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        onPressed: null,
      ),
    ],

    title: Text("App Bar"),
    centerTitle: true,
  ),
```

and below I have the body with BoxDecoration and image that is selected with Image Picker:

```
body: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: _image == null
            ? MemoryImage(kTransparentImage)
            : FileImage(_image),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
```

Is is possible for this button in the AppBar:

```
IconButton(
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.clear,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        onPressed: null,
      ),
```

to have onPressed function to clear the image from the BoxDecoration (it is null for now). I was thinking the simple inserting the kTransparentImage would work, but how would I go around doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can set `_image` to `null` and call `setState` 
code snippet

```
IconButton(
    icon: Icon(
      Icons.clear,
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
    onPressed: () {
      _image = null;
      setState(() {});
    },
  ),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:transparent_image/transparent_image.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  File _image;
  final picker = ImagePicker();

  Future _getImage() async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      if (pickedFile != null) {
        _image = File(pickedFile.path);

        print('_image: $_image');
      } else {
        print('No image selected');
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add_a_photo, color: Colors.white),
            onPressed: () => _getImage(),
          ),
          //this should be clear image button
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.clear,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              _image = null;
              setState(() {});
            },
          ),
        ],
        title: Text("App Bar"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: _image == null
              ? MemoryImage(kTransparentImage)
              : FileImage(_image),
        ),
      )),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _getImage,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Nevermind, tested it and everything works perfectly. Thank you a lot for your answer, these simplest solutions are always the hardest for me.